# What are these glitches in my listview when scrolling?

Tags: qt, listview, qml, pyside2

I'm writing a file conversion software in QT for Python where you will be able to drag files into the software, click a convert button, and drag out the output files. When a user drags files into the software, all the names of the files are added into a ListView.

When a user drags files into the ListView, it calls the `backend.addToPaths(url)` function with each of the file paths that were dragged into it. This function then appends all of the file paths into an internal list of file paths, then updates the listview, calling the updateList (paths) function in the main.qml file with all of the file names, which clears the listview and then appends back all of the file names, the old ones, and the new ones dragged in.

All of the file names are added to the list view correctly, but then when I scroll around inside of the list view, it produces these very strange rendering bugs, [as shown in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gbmb3qFR1qY), or in these images:

Image 1:
[image: Image 1]

Image 2:
[image: Image 2]

Image 3:
[image: Image 3]

At first I thought it could be due to clipping, so I removed that, and nothing changed. I then tried increasing the listview's display margin, and then its cacheBuffer, but it still didn't help. I also tried setting pixelAligned to true, but that still didn't work. I'm guessing it's probably because QT isn't very good at handling listmodels being updated or changed, but I don't really know.

Here's a simplified version of my `main.qml` file if needed:

```
ListView {
    id: inputFileView
    // @disable-check M16
    objectName: "inputFileView"
    clip: true
    boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
    flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick
    displayMarginBeginning: 100
    displayMarginEnd: 100

    function updateList(paths) {
        console.log("updating list");
        inputFileModel.clear();
        paths.forEach( function (item) {
            inputFileModel.append({
                'name': item
            });
        });
    }

    model: ListModel {
        id: inputFileModel
    }
    delegate: Item {
        Row {
            id: row1
            Text {
                text: name
            }
        }
    }

    DropArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onDropped: {
            drop.urls.forEach( function (url) {
                backend.addToPaths(url)
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see things like this when threading is involved. Are you doing anything outside of the main thread on the Python side? If so, the problem is likely to come back.

Comment: I'm not currently, but I will probably need to when executing ffmpeg and imagemagick tasks for the file conversion, although I won't need to change anything in the gui or qml in that thread, so I think it'd be fine

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Looks like a graphics driver issue. Please run with the `QSG_INFO` environment variable set to `1` and include the output in your question. Also your Qt version.

Comment: @musicamante i tried to simplify my code as much as I could, it's just that I didn't know what was causing the problem, so I gave everything that I thought could have a chance of causing the problem, like maybe it couldd've been something to do with the flickable, or maybe adding new elements to the listview; I also just wanted enough to explain what my project was and what was going on in the backend

Comment: @eramne sorry, for some reason I didn't see the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it was a bug with PySide2? I noticed someone replaced the Pyside tag with the PySide2 tag, and I didn't even show the python code that would've clarified that I was using that version, so I wondered if it meant that the issue was only in PySide2, so I switched from that to PySide6, and it worked. I have no idea what was causing it, but I guess it's fine now.

Comment: Sorry but this answer is not really useful, as we don't know what caused the problem. *If* it is a bug, it's important that we understand the source of that bug so that it could be possibly submitted and solved, with the result of helping others in the process.

Comment: should i have added it as a comment instead?

Comment: Well, a comment would probably be a better fit, but it's already here. If nobody raises a flag about it, you can leave it. Just consider this for future reference.